# service status of hostnames from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code that starts a service called uvnc_service on all hostnames I have in a text file called find.txt (see below). I want to add some sort of check to test if the service is already running on it so if it is - do nothing and output a message to the screen saying that its already running or if its not running on one of the hosts in the find.txt file - start the service and then output/append the hostname to this file.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

find.txt...

```
pc1
pc2
pc3
```

...

```
set service = uvnc_service
for /F %%a in (c:\temp\find.txt) do sc \\%%a start %service% && >> out.txt echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service control to query the machine and see the status of the service ie is it running

http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html

Try this

```
set service = uvnc_service
for /F %%a in (c:\find.txt) do call :servicecheck %%a

:servicecheck
sc \\%1 query %service% | FIND "RUNNING" 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO STARTSERVICE %1
GOTO END

:STARTSERVICE
 sc \\%1 start %service% && >> out.txt echo %1

:END
```

I cant test it on my machine and i haven't done batch in a while so it might not be perfect

Comment: Hi, I'm using the the sc command and I get the following output: [SC] StartService FAILED 1056: An instance of the service is already running. [SC] StartService FAILED 1056: An instance of the service is already running. from my list of hostnames - only pc1 should be echo'd to the resulting out.txt file, but instead i get all the hostnames? @decad

Comment: yes. at the moment, the uvnc_service is running on both pc2 and pc3, but not pc1. when i run the code, i get pc1 pc2 and pc3 in the out.txt instead of just pc1. can you help? @decad

Comment: is the service running on all of them? your batch file is looping over all of the hosts and trying to start the service and dump anything returned into out.txt, if the service is running already on all your hosts i would expect to see all your hosts in the out.txt

Comment: I see, so its not running on host one have you tried manually running the command for just pc1?

Comment: the service is running on pc2 and pc3, but not pc1. @decad

Comment: yes. it works, if only pc1 is in the find.txt file, but when i add more hostnames in that list, the out.txt just outputs everything that was in the find.txt file @decad

Comment: and with multiple hosts in the find file it doesn't start the service a tall? ignoring whats output

Comment: thats right. i think the logic needs to be looked into. i'm thinking of an 'if' statement, but i'm not sure how to go about this? @decad

Comment: Well based on the current batch file adding more names to find.txt file shouldn't change the commands that get run on each loop for the for loop, so it should be the same command thats running which is confusing that it breaks by adding more hosts

Comment: i've just tested it - the sc command does work - it can see that service on pc1 is not running and its already running on pc2 and pc3 so it does start on pc1 and says that its already running on pc2 and 3, its just that the out.txt is a bit screwed up @decad

Comment: only pc1 should appear in out.txt,but instead it just outputs all the hostnames that the sc command went through. @decad

Comment: how should i go about rectifying this problem?

Comment: ah right that makes more sense, it is because you are outputting to the text file on every command you do regardless of what it is doing. I would suggest you look into the sc query command to check the status of the service and only attempt to start it if its not running and then output that to the out.txt file.

Comment: the only thing i've found relevant is the 'sc query' command - i could use sc query uvnc_service | find "RUNNING", so wrapping this into - for /F %%a in (c:\temp\find.txt) do sc query uvnc_service | find "RUNNING"? -Decad

Comment: there is a problem with the query statement - sc query fax | FIND "RUNNING"; replaced fax to %service% - still no joy. does this have to be in capitals? -Decad

Comment: Sorry if you look again i have made an edit. As i said its been a while since i've done batch its slowly coming back to me.

Comment: the code now has placed the hostnames pc2 and pc3 in the out.txt file instead of just pc1. is this something to do with the error levels? -decad

Comment: yes try inverting the IF so its errorlevel == 1, it was a guess as to the errorlevel returned by SC, sorry bit rusty

Comment: thanks for your time and effort - its more or less ready. will make a few interface related changes to make this look nicer and upload it here. @decad